# Potential leaks in iOS project

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

Hello i have this function, that gets dummy data from file in project:
Issues are shown in those lines:

`NSString   *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"StatisticsDataJSON" ofType: @"TXT"];` - **potential leak of an object.**

`NSMutableDictionary *statisticsResponse = [jsonParser objectWithString:data];` - **potential leak of an object stored into 'jsonParser'**

`for (id key in statisticsResponse)` { - **potential leak of an object stored into 'statisticArray'**

`for (int i = 0; i < statsForDate.count; i++)` { - **potential leak of an object stored into 's'**

```
if (self.statistics==nil)
{
    self.statistics = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    NSString   *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"StatisticsDataJSON" ofType: @"TXT"];
    NSError    *error = nil;
    NSString   *data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path
                                             encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                error: &error];
    //NSLog(@"%@",data);

    SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *statisticsResponse = [jsonParser objectWithString:data];

    for (id key in statisticsResponse) {
        NSArray *statsForDate = [statisticsResponse objectForKey:key];
        NSMutableArray *statisticArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i = 0; i < statsForDate.count; i++) {
            Statistic *s = [[Statistic alloc]init];
            s.locationId = [[statsForDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"locationId"];
            int value =[[[statsForDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"visits"] integerValue];
            s.visits = value;
            value =[[[statsForDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"totalUsers"] integerValue];
            s.totalUsers = value;
            value= [[[statsForDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"uploads"] integerValue];
            s.uploads = value;
            value = [[[statsForDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"downloads"] integerValue];
            s.downloads = value;
            value = [[[statsForDate objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"apps"] integerValue];
            s.apps = value;
            [statisticArray addObject:s];
        }
        [self.statistics setObject:statisticArray forKey:key];
    };
}
```

I have found that autorelease in ststisticsResponse - resolves the problem:

```
NSMutableDictionary *statisticsResponse = [[jsonParser objectWithString:data]autorelease];
```

But then something fails in SBJsonStreamParserAccumulator.m in dealoc function.

**What is the problem?**

Comment: Are you not using ARC?

Comment: old project - not ARC

Comment: I suggest you update it.  From the looks of it whoever wrote it has no idea about memory management.  Either that or you are not showing the whole picture.  Everything that you alloc / init you need to release later.  Are you doing that?

Comment: after this, objects in this method are never used

Comment: Then you are creating memory leaks.  If you alloc something without releasing it...that's a leak (not the only way, but one way)

Comment: ok, i have tried to release "path" variable, lets say on the end of if - app crashes

Comment: I'm not going to walk you through the basics of memory management.  There is an entire article on it by Apple that I suggest you read.  I never said anything about the `path` variable anyway.

Comment: The path is OK, you get the message a line later from the issue in your case... self.statistics = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]; should be self.statistics = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];

Comment: Anyway, read the whole message and look at what object it says it is leaking, not the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the warnings about potential leaks come on the line *after* the potential leak, because that's the first point at which the referenced object is technically "leaked". So your current fixes are probably over-releasing and causing crashes.

The first statement in your question actually refers to a leak in this line, immediately before:

```
self.statistics = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

You've got no further reference to that allocated dictionary, and it's a retained property, so you have a leak.

```
self.statistics = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease];
```

Will fix that one. The next one, you have to release the jsonParser when you've finished with it (**after the parsing is done**):

```
[jsonParser release];
```

I'm not going to go through all of them but you should get the idea. Basically you need to read the memory management guide, or update to ARC.

Pay attention to the variable names in the warnings. They tell you where the leak is.

Comment: thanks, before i have seen you'r answer i handled all leaks except the self.statistics. And you'r answer resolved my last problem =)